# Disable mouse hover over time.

Tags: windows-server-2012

On this Windows Server 2012 PC if you hover over the time at the bottom right, a black side bar pops out.

How do I disable this?

Other solutions I've looked at seem to be covering task bar previewing, or window selecting by hover.

Comment: I believe the proper name for it is the charm bar.

Answer (score 0):

Save the following as a .REG file, import and see if it helps:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell\EdgeUI]
"DisableTRCorner"=dword:00000001
"DisableCharmsHint"=dword:00000001
```